# Pass data from Service to activity launched by the Service

Tags: android, android-activity, service

What I wanna do is to pass data from a Service S to an activity A.

However, in my case, A is not starting S and then waiting for an answer from it : S is always running in the background.

I'd like to use an Intent with a bundle attached to it, because my data are Strings and Booleans.

I do not know how to proceed to make this work. (I've read about BroadcastReceiver and other stuff).

Here is when I start the activity in the Service :

```
public void answerFromServer(ArrayList<Contact> listeDemand, ArrayList<Contact> listeAccepted){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateContactActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    ArrayList<String> listAllDemandName = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listAllDemandId = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;

    ArrayList<String> listAllAccName = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listAllAccId = new ArrayList<>();
    int j = 0;

    for(Contact contact : listeDemand){
        String string = contact.getName();
        int Id = contact.getId();
        Boolean online = contact.isOnline();
        listAllDemandName.add(string);
        listAllDemandId.add(Id);
        bundle.putBoolean("onlineD" + Integer.toString(i), online);
        i++;
    }

    for(Contact contact : listeAccepted){
        String string = contact.getName();
        int Id = contact.getId();
        Boolean online = contact.isOnline();
        listAllAccName.add(string);
        listAllAccId.add(Id);
        bundle.putBoolean("onlineA" + Integer.toString(j), online);
        j++;
    }

    bundle.putStringArrayList("nameDemandList", listAllDemandName);
    bundle.putIntegerArrayList("idDemandList", listAllDemandId);
    bundle.putStringArrayList("nameAccList", listAllAccName);
    bundle.putIntegerArrayList("idAccList", listAllAccId);

    intent.putExtra("contactRequest", bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.user_jaune)
                    .setContentTitle("RG 2.1")
                    .setContentText("Mise(s) Ã  jour contact")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(50, mBuilder.build());
```

Thanks,

Comment: show your code starting activity

Comment: for small data travel like one or two values passing values via intent is ok. But if you want to share huge amount of data, a sqlite database should be better....

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski : the activity is starting when you click on the notification. I edited my post.

Comment: Ok but what exactly you are having problems with? Reading these values in A or what?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski : That's as you said. I do not know how to read the values in A when S launch A.

Comment: Well, ok. See the answer below then but my question now is - is the code that puts stuff into bundle yours? If not, let me tell that using code w/o understanding what it does is quite risky and usually gives "negative benefits".

Comment: Yeah, no need to worry about that, the code is entirely mine !
The thing is that I am doing a lot of things with my activity (receiving data from a Service, from a server, passing data to another activity) which is why it is difficult to deal with everything at a time.
Thanks you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> That's as you said. I do not know how to read the values in A when S launch A

It does not matter what caused A launch really. All data is in the bundle so something like this in your `onCreate()` should solve your problem:

```
Bundle contactRequest;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   contactRequest = extras.getBundle("contactRequest");

   // then get all the stuff you placed there the same way
   idAccList = contactRequest .getIntegerArrayList("idAccList");

   ...
}
```